# Change CSS based on Hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, css, datetime

I writing a page that with be displayed 24/7 and will have not have any interaction by a per. I would like the CSS to change based on the hour and minutes (i.e. 8:30 instead of 8. I found a solution based solely on hours but can't get minutes into the mix, I also was to take it a step further so that once it hits the time that triggers a CSS change that it also refreshes the page to change the CSS.

```
var d=new Date();
var twi_am_start = 6;
var twi_am_end = 14;
var twi_pm_start = 14;
var twi_pm_end = 22;

if (d.getHours() >= twi_am_start && d.getHours() < twi_am_end)
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/first.css" type="text/css">');
else if (d.getHours() >= twi_pm_start && d.getHours() < twi_pm_end )
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/second.css" type="text/css">');
else
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/third.css" type="text/css">');
```

Comment: Depending on the ammount of code, I agree with Sven van de Scheur, just add it on the same stylesheet and use a class on the body...
Unless your CSS for each will be too big to load on one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your realy want to change css files based on time, try this:

```
var now = new Date(),
    hours = now.getHours(),
    minutes = now.getMinutes() + hours * 60,
    link = document.createElement('link'),
    href;

var TIME_INTERVALS = { // in minutes
    AM_START: 6 * 60,
    AM_END_PM_START: 14 * 60,
    PM_END: 22 * 60
}

var CSS_FILES = {
    AM_START: 'first.css',
    AM_END_PM_START: 'second.css',
    PM_END: 'third.css'
}

link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';

if (minutes > TIME_INTERVALS.AM_START) {

    if (minutes > TIME_INTERVALS.AM_END_PM_START) {

        if (minutes > TIME_INTERVALS.PM_END) {
            // > PM_START hours now 
            href = CSS_FILES.PM_END;
        } else {
            // > AM_END_PM_START && < PM_END time
            href = CSS_FILES.AM_END_PM_START;
        }

    } else {
        // AM_START - AM_END
        href = CSS_FILES.AM_START;
    }
} else {
    // 00.00 - AM_START
    href = CSS_FILES.PM_END;
}

link.href = '../css/' + href;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/mvx42L92/

Comment: it looks to work, but how do i have it change as followed:

00:00-06:40 = third
06:40-14:40 = first
14:40-22:40 = second
22:40-24:00 = third

Comment: you need to change only time breakpoints, updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mvx42L92/1/ in `TIME_INTERVALS` object. Just add 40 minutes to hours (see comment in fiddle)

Comment: I figured that part out, i can just use decimal hours.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to the body of the page based on your time:

`<body class="morning">`

and then apply css to it:

```
.morning { background: orange; }
.afternoon { background: lightblue; }
.evening { background: darkblue; }
```

(picked some random names for colors)

Answer (score 0):

To get minutes instead of hours, you can use this method :

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();
```

Now you can adapt it with your script.